# Confirming if a radiobox is checked

Tags: javascript, html

Currently i want to check if a radiobox is checked using html and javascript only. When i click the radio buttons, i want a javascript alert message to pop up saying that this particular button has been clicked, but nothing comes up.

Would anyone have a solution as to why my code has errors?

```
function checked()
{
if(document.getElementById("s1").checked)
{
  alert("Small");
}               
    if(document.getElementById("s2").checked)
    {
   alert("Medium");
}
if(document.getElementById("s3").checked)
{
   alert("Large");
}
if(document.getElementById("s4").checked)
{
   alert("Extra Large");
}
}

<input type="radio" id="s1" name="shirtsize" value="small" onchange="checked()"/>Small
<input type="radio" id="s2" name="shirtsize" value="medium" onchange="checked()"/>Medium
<input type="radio" id="s3" name="shirtsize" value="large" onchange="checked()"/>Large
<input type="radio" id="s4" name="shirtsize" value="extralarge" onchange="checked()"/>Extra Large
```

your input would really be appreciated

Comment: Did you try "onclick" instead of "onchange" event ?

Comment: I did, it gave me the same results! Strigidis

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your function name to `radio_checked()` from `checked()` as checked is reserved keyword and will cause error!

Mark up goes here:

```
<input type="radio" id="s1" name="shirtsize" value="small" onchange="radio_checked()"/>Small
```

**Script**

```
function radio_checked()
{
    // ......... rest of code .........
}
```

### [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/52hJR/1/)

You were getting error because `checked` is a property for checkboxes and radio buttons and you're creating a user defined function with the same name i.e. `checked()` which will cost you errors, your rest of the code will not execute.

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly, and i am receiving input whenever i click the buttons, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you have to make following changes
html

```
<input type="radio" id="s1" name="shirtsize" value="small" onClick="radioChecked()"/>Small
```

script

```
function radioChecked()
{
if(document.getElementById("s1").checked)
{
  alert("Small");
}               
    if(document.getElementById("s2").checked)
    {
   alert("Medium");
}
if(document.getElementById("s3").checked)
{
   alert("Large");
}
if(document.getElementById("s4").checked)
{
   alert("Extra Large");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this , it will gave what you want

```
var rad = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
var value;
for (var i = 0; i < rad.length; i++) {
    if (rad[i].type === 'radio' && rad[i].checked) {

        alert("checked");     
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this one:

> Plain JS

**script**

```
var show = function(v){
    alert(v + ' was clicked');
};
```

**html**

```
<input type="radio" id="s1" name="shirtsize" value="small" onchange="show(this.value)"/>Small
<input type="radio" id="s2" name="shirtsize" value="medium" onchange="show(this.value)"/>Medium
<input type="radio" id="s3" name="shirtsize" value="large" onchange="show(this.value)"/>Large
<input type="radio" id="s4" name="shirtsize" value="extralarge" onchange="show(this.value)"/>Extra Large
```

> JQuery

**script**

```
$(function(){
    $("#s1, #s2, #s3, #s4").on('change', function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        alert($(this).val() + ' was clicked');
    });
})
```

**html**

```
<input type="radio" id="s1" name="shirtsize" value="small"/>Small
<input type="radio" id="s2" name="shirtsize" value="medium"/>Medium
<input type="radio" id="s3" name="shirtsize" value="large"/>Large
<input type="radio" id="s4" name="shirtsize" value="extralarge"/>Extra Large
```